# Why runtime! is not working?

Tags: filetype

Add customise filetype setting file do.vim inside ftdetect folder.
Edit gvim/8.2/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim:
`runtime! $HOME/.vim/ftdetect/*.vim` 
Open file, run `verbose set ft?`. From print, filetype is still default conf.
  `filetype=conf`
        `Last set from ~/TOOLS/gvim/8.2/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim line 2193`

If comment out `runtime!` and add `so $HOME/.vim/ftdetect/do.vim`.
Open file, run `verbose set ft?`, it shows correct filetype setting.
  `filetype=tcl`
       `Last set from ~/bin/vim/env/vim/ftdetect/do.vim line 6`
Note: $HOME/.vim is soft link to ~/bin/vim/env/vim.

Not sure why runtime! is not working.
[image]

Comment: Is the screenshot taken from $VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim? Did you modify line 2182? It should read `runtime! ftdetect/*.vim`. The `runtime`-command already takes care of searching your local .vim directory (and all the other paths in `'runtimepath'`).

Comment: Yes, you are right. If I revert the change and use default runtime! command, it's working. So problem is the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit gvim/8.2/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim

Messing with standard config files is discouraged unless one clearly understands what's he doing. (And even then the chances are one shouldn't do this, never ever).

> `runtime! $HOME/.vim/ftdetect/*.vim`

This is wrong for a pretty simple reason: basically what `:runtime!` does, it iterates through all paths in `:h 'runtimepath'`, prepends each one as a prefix to your path and then tries to `:source` the resulting file name/wildcard. Hence the right syntax is `runtime! ftdetect/*.vim`.

However, it's already in `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim` which will be sourced upon `:filetype on` and so it needs not be touched AT ALL.